# Why RequestQueue for Volley must be Singleton?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have read some blocks for Volley. All are requsting to use RequestQueue as SingleTon.

Why It should be singleton?

Why can't we create RequestQueue whenever we want?

Comment: Because It's a good programming practice to reuse objects.

Answer (score 4):

Volley is designed to queue all your requests. It wouldn't make sense to have more than one queue, and that's why it's a singleton.

Comment: I was thinking like  If we have two request queue , they will operate in parallel, and we can get fast response.Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. Volley is already optimized for parallelism. If you need a request to run sooner than something else you can use `Priority`

Answer (score 0):

you can use defined `RequestQueue` as `public static` in the `class` and use that anywhere of your project:

```
public static RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
```